# Splitting string in Python starting from the first numeric character

Tags: python, regex

I need to manage string in Python in this way:

I have this kind of strings with '>=', '=', '<=', '<', '>' in front of them, for example:

```
'>=1_2_3'
'<2_3_2'
```

what I want to achieve is splitting the strings to obtain, respectively:

```
'>=', '1_2_3' 
'<', '2_3_2'
```

basically I need to split them starting from the first numeric character.

There's a way to achieve this result with regular expressions without iterating over the string checking if a character is a number or a '_'?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
re.split(r'(^[^\d]+)', string)[1:]
```

Example:

```
>>> re.split(r'(^[^\d]+)', '>=1_2_3')[1:]
['>=', '1_2_3']

>>> re.split(r'(^[^\d]+)', '<2_3_2')[1:]
['<', '2_3_2']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

strings = ['>=1_2_3','<2_3_2']

for s in strings:
    mat = re.match(r'([^\d]*)(\d.*)', s)
    print mat.groups()
```

Outputs:

```
('>=', '1_2_3')
('<', '2_3_2')
```

This just groups everything up until the first digit in one group, then that first digit and everything after into a second.

You can access the individual groups with `mat.group(1)`, `mat.group(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can split using this regex:

```
(?<=[<>=])(?=\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX3xL1/1)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way but you can split with a capture then join the second two elements:

```
values = re.split(r'(\d)', '>=1_2_3', maxsplit = 1)
values = [values[0], values[1] + values[2]]
```